# map a vector of single-character strings to a PersistentMap

Tags: dictionary, vector, clojure

I'm trying to transliterate a list through a hashmap, something like this:

```
(map {"a" 0 "b" 1 "c" 2} ["a","c","b","a"])
```

Which I want to spit out:

```
[0,2,1,0]
```

How do I do this?

Correction:  The above works, but but this does not:

```
  (map {"a" 0 "b" 1 "c" 2} (vec "acba"))
```

Whats different here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `mapv` instead

```
user=> (map {"a" 0 "b" 1 "c" 2} ["a" "c" "b" "a"])
(0 2 1 0)
user=> (mapv {"a" 0 "b" 1 "c" 2} ["a" "c" "b" "a"])
[0 2 1 0]
```

Also:

```
user=> (map {"a" 0 "b" 1 "c" 2} (vec "acba"))
(nil nil nil nil)
user=> (vec "acba")
[\a \c \b \a]
user=> (= \a "a")
false
```

This works (but is roundabout):

```
user=> (mapv {"a" 0 "b" 1 "c" 2} (map str (vec "acba")))
(0 2 1 0)
```

Comment: `(mapv {"a" 0 "b" 1 "c" 2} (map str "acba"))` is sufficient in the last example -- you just need a sequence of strings, not chars.

Comment: Just for fun: if you were working with keywords: `((apply juxt [:a :c :b :a]) {:a 0 :b 1 :c 2})`

Comment: @ToBeReplaced Agreed - this occurred to me as well. I was just working off the questioner's example.

Comment: @Kyle - because keywords are also functions that return their corresponding value from a map. Nice! :)